# Understanding of JWT for python flask app

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I'm trying to understand the JWT handling in flask.
I have gone through the following doc.

[https://iq.opengenus.org/jwt-authentication-flask/#:~:text=%40jwt_required%20is%20the%20decorator%20used%20to%20make%20a,JWT%20Authentication%20in%20REST%20API%20in%20Flask.%20Enjoy](https://iq.opengenus.org/jwt-authentication-flask/#:%7E:text=%40jwt_required%20is%20the%20decorator%20used%20to%20make%20a,JWT%20Authentication%20in%20REST%20API%20in%20Flask.%20Enjoy).

Here I see, we are authenticating the user and password and creating a token in header from server side.

What if I'm getting the token from Client header alreadt. What steps to be taken care from Flask App? We just check the Token with secret_key and how to validate the token is correct and so on.
I'm using it for the first time. Please help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth reading [Token-Based Authentication With Flask](https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/).

Your server code should [decode and validate](https://realpython.com/token-based-authentication-with-flask/#decode-token) the presented JWT token.

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through it.  Is it possible to decode with a secret_key when i'm not encoding with secret_key?

Comment: From the frontend, Login is authenticated and token is sent to header for every Api. So how to use the secret_key from server side ?

Comment: What do you mean by "i'm not encoding with secret_key"? Which component here is creating/encoding the JWT? Is it not the same component (your app server) that's receiving the API request and decoding/validating the JWT?

Comment: As per the links I see, we are creating the token after authentication from app server and encoding with secret_key and similarly decoding with secret_key. In my case, authentication and token creation is taken care in the front end.

Comment: I just want to know if decoding the token received from frontend with secret_key works ?

Comment: If you encoded the token and you have access to the secret key at decode time, then you can decode the token.